# JOLT- How to sort data basis on json key value pair

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I would like to sort the data of JSON Object key values and the arrangement should be in ascending format. and the second challenge i can see this, number of questions and answers count is not fixed to three, can be increase or decreases.

Input :

```
{
  ".0.answer": "In tag functionality ",
  ".0.question": "Provide a brief description",
  ".0.questionSequence": 1,
  ".1.answer": "In Git if we want to know",
  ".1.question": "Use Case Description ",
  ".1.questionSequence": 3,
  ".2.answer": "In Git if we want to know PIT",
  ".2.question": "Business Justification ",
  ".2.questionSequence": 2
}
```

Desired output :

```
{
  ".0.answer": "In tag functionality ",
  ".0.question": "Provide a brief description",
  ".0.questionSequence": 1,
  ".2.answer": "In Git if we want to know PIT",
  ".2.question": "Business Justification ",
  ".2.questionSequence": 2,
  ".1.answer": "In Git if we want to know",
  ".1.question": "Use Case Description ",
  ".1.questionSequence": 3
}
```

JOLT :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "*questionSequence"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi, Im not sure if this is possible using just jolt. there could be a solution if the value of question\answer sequence is alphabetic instead of numeric or the sequence is not going to be greater than 9 .

Comment: I think this question needs to change to specify that you want the question sequence to be in ascending order. Needs clarity

Comment: @MikeR, Question sequence to be in ascending.

Comment: @samersaleh, can you suggest this using the numeric, i can convert this alphabet to numeric, like a-1,b-2,c-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. please read the comments on each spec to understand how we get to the desired result:

```
[
  // group each question\answer\sequence under
  // their own parent using the index attached to each field 0,1,2...
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      ".*.*": {
        "@": "&(0,1).&"
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  //create new sequence field of string type based
  // on the integer value of .*.questionSequence. The
  // new sequence will be used for sorting, but since
  // its number string we need to make sure that the order
  // remains correct even when the number goes into a new
  // tenth digit 10s,20s,30s... To overcome this we can 
  // add prefix represent number of digits in a string number
  // For example 2=>1.2 , 12=>2.12, 102=>3.102 and so on.
  // This will ensure that 9 will come before 10 because
  // it will be stored as 1.9 and 2.10
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "sequenceOrderStr": "=toString(@(1,\\.&1\\.questionSequence))",
        "numberOfDigit": "=size(@(1,sequenceOrderStr))",
        "finalSequenceOrder": "=concat(@(1,numberOfDigit),'.',@(1,sequenceOrderStr))"
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  // regroup each question\anwer\sequence field
  // under thew new sequence order field created above
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        ".*.*": "@(1,finalSequenceOrder).&"
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  // sort based on the finalSequenceOrder value
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  // re structure to flatten the list as 
  // the original input but with the correct order
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```